# Maven local repo not updated with latest dependency

Tags: eclipse, maven, maven-2, maven-3, maven-plugin

My project has a pom.xml which I did deploy to a remote repository inside my company

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>ProjectMav</groupId>
<artifactId>ProjectMav</artifactId>
<version>1.0</version>
<distributionManagement>
    <repository>
        <id>man-release</id>
        <name>mav release repo</name>
        <url>http://xxxxxx.net/repositories/mav-release/</url>
    </repository>
    <snapshotRepository>
        <id>mav-snapshots</id>
        <name>mav snapshots repo</name>
        <url>http://xxxxxx.net/repositories/mav-snapshots/</url>
    </snapshotRepository>
</distributionManagement>
<build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

After I do a 'mvn deploy' I did browse the remote repository and I see the project there

I have another project that is dependent on the above mentioned 'ProjectMav' and it's POM.xml is as follows

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>mavtest</groupId>
<artifactId>mavtest-suite</artifactId>
<version>1.0</version>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ProjectMav</groupId>
        <artifactId>ProjectMav</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>mav-release</id>
        <name>mav release repo</name>
        <url>http://xxxxxx.net/repositories/mav-release/</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
<build>
    <testSourceDirectory>src/com/mav/</testSourceDirectory>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>/resources</directory>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </resource>
    </resources>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

Now from eclipse if I do a Maven>update project it does not get the latest version of my 'ProjectMav' to my local repository.

But if I clear all the files in my local repo and do a maven update it gets my project

Any idea what's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the issue is that the maven eclipse plugin's `update` doesn't actually do a `mvn install` which is what you need if you want to override the `1.0` deployed version. The way the mvn eclipse plugin orders classpath dependencies (which you can clearly see in the *package explorer* is to put the dependency jars first and then the resolved upstream projects after the jars). This seems to work fine for SNAPSHOT projects as the plugin knows to use your project and not the jars but for release jars it gets confused (or at least I have noticed it to).

That being said you should avoid this issue altogether by changing the version of your local one to:

```
<version>1.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
```

Then in your downstream projects that depend on `ProjectMav` you update their dependencies to `1.1-SNAPSHOT`. The management of versions can be tricky so you might want to look into the maven release plugin and have it deal with version-ing of your project when you deploy.

Comment: I tried changing my ProjectMav's pom.xml version to <version>1.1-SNAPSHOT</version> and updated one of the downstream project to <version>2.1-SNAPSHOT</version> in dependency. Even then update project through eclipse is not downloading the latest snapshot of ProjectMav to my local repo.

Comment: Well its not going to show up in your maven repo (ie ~/.m2) because the eclipse plugin is now relying on the code from the eclipse project itself and not the local installed artifact. If you want to see the project in your local repo and/or use the command line you will need to run `mvn install` on your project.